# Approximation of sum of square

Tags: calculus

I would like to know if there is a way to compute/approximate this formula:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n (x_i-y_i)^2$$

when we only know:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n x_i$$ and $$\sum_{i=0}^n y_i$$

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically there isn't.  You could have the sum of $x$ and $y$ very large, but the sum of differences squared be very small or the other way around.  Even with $n=2$, think about $x_1=y_1=10000, x_2=y_2=20000$.  Your first sum is zero.  Alternately, think about $x_1=-y_1=1000, x_2=-y_2=-1000$  The first sum is $8,000,000$ and the last two are zero.

Comment: We might also know $$\sum_{i=0}^n (x_i)²$$ and  $$\sum_{i=0}^n (y_i)²$$ , then maybe it's easier ?

Comment: You have the relation $\sum (x_i-y_i)^2=\sum x_i^2-2x_iy_i+y_i^2$ but if the $x$'s and $y$'s are correlated it can destroy things.  If they are not correlated, the cross term will average to zero over many points so you might be able to neglect it.